# OLSRD in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ad-hoc-network, olsrd

I installed Olsrd version 0.9.0.3 and when I run Olsrd in the root, I have the following results:

```
Build date: 2016-10-14 15:19:03 on ubuntu
http://www.olsr.org   

Parsing file: "/etc/olsrd/olsrd.conf"
Link quality fish eye 0
Plugin: olsrd_txtinfo.so.0.1   

Interface Defaultssetting ifs_in_curr_cfg = 0
IPv4 broadcast/multicast : AUTO (d)
Mode : mesh (d)
IPv6 multicast : ff02::6d
HELLO emission/validity : 2.00 (d)/20.00 (d)
TC emission/validity : 5.00 (d)/300.00 (d)
MID emission/validity : 5.00 (d)/300.00 (d)
HNA emission/validity : 5.00 (d)/300.00 (d)
Autodetect changes : yes
IPv4 broadcast/multicast : AUTO
Mode : mesh
IPv6 multicast : ::
HELLO emission/validity : 0.00/0.00
TC emission/validity : 0.00/0.00
MID emission/validity : 0.00/0.00
HNA emission/validity : 0.00/0.00
Autodetect changes : no
IPv4 broadcast/multicast : AUTO
Mode : mesh
IPv6 multicast : ::
HELLO emission/validity : 0.00/0.00
TC emission/validity : 0.00/0.00
MID emission/validity : 0.00/0.00
HNA emission/validity : 0.00/0.00
Autodetect changes : no
Added 0.0.0.0 to IP deny set
Added 127.0.0.1 to IP deny set

---- Interface configuration ----

Checking <OLSRd-Interfac:
No such interface!
Checking <OLSRd-Interfac:
No such interface!
No interfaces detected! This might be intentional, but it also might mean that your configuration is fubar.
I will continue after 5 seconds.
Using 'etx_ff' algorithm for lq calculation.
---------- LOADING LIBRARY olsrd_txtinfo.so.0.1 ----------
OLSRD txtinfo plugin 0.1 by Lorenz Schori
Checking plugin interface version: 5 - OK
Trying to fetch plugin init function: OK
Trying to fetch parameter table and it's size...
Sending parameters...
Running plugin_init function...
---------- LIBRARY olsrd_txtinfo.so.0.1 LOADED ----------

-- ALL PLUGINS LOADED! --

Main address: 0.0.0.0

Scheduler started - polling every 50 ms
```

Could you please let me know how I can configure the interfaces?
Thank you in advance,

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It's better to ask this question in [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question. It may be more suitable for [ubuntu.se] or [su] instead. The [help] has information regarding the types of question that are on-topic here.